# Activity lifecycle strange behavior in sleep mode (libGDX game)

Tags: android, android-activity, libgdx

I have very strange behavior of Activity in my LibGDX game - when I play game and then press power button sending device to sleep mode. I've added logs to Activity's callback methods and that's what I see:

```
05-14 16:32:51.694: I/BP(32656): onPause()
05-14 16:32:51.704: I/BP(32656): onStop()
05-14 16:32:51.854: I/BPApplication(32656): BPApplication.onConfigurationChanged()
05-14 16:32:51.854: I/BP(32656): BP.onConfigurationChanged()
```

At this point all goes right way. Further some strange begins:

```
05-14 16:40:42.774: I/BP(32656): onRestart()
05-14 16:40:42.774: I/BP(32656): onStart()
05-14 16:40:43.064: I/BP(32656): onResume()
05-14 16:40:44.566: I/BP(32656): BP.onConfigurationChanged()
05-14 16:40:44.566: I/BPApplication(32656): BPApplication.onConfigurationChanged()
05-14 16:40:49.761: I/System.out(32656): screen resize w = 480, h=800 // libGDX callback
05-14 16:40:49.911: I/System.out(32656): GAME RESUMED...              // libGDX callback
05-14 16:40:50.471: I/System.out(32656): screen resize w = 800, h=480 // libGDX callback
05-14 16:40:59.010: I/System.out(32656): GAME PAUSED                  // libGDX callback
05-14 16:41:00.711: I/BP(32656): onPause()
05-14 16:41:00.801: I/BP(32656): onStop()
05-14 16:41:00.851: I/BP(32656): onRestart()
.... this cycle repeats 5 - 10 times ....
```

So as you can see problem is that Activity.onRestart() and further callbacks calls when device is asleep. And this repeats 5-10 times during near one minute.
I don't understand why Activity restarts and what are performing this operation.
Im my game I have billing service v2 (implemented by other programmer) and setup AlarmManager for restore free game.

I am completely confused with this issue so any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

It seems that deal in libGDX - I've build another project with same library version and it behaves exactly like my game.

Comment: There often seems to be some changing of screen orientation (and possibly even size?) when going into sleep mode (in effect, sleep has an orientation).  You might try indicating in your Manifest that you will handle configuration changes within your app.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but I already handle orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, you should have something like-

```
<activity 
  android:name=".YourAppName"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it already added. I understand your thoughts - onConfigurationChanged() but Activity is not destroyed it simply restarts several times, then pause for few minutes, then activity restarts again.

Comment: It's the bahavior of Android I believe, not of LibGDX. Is it causing any problem? What's your targetSdkVersion in the manifest?

Comment: Indirectly - yes. Life restoring implemented via AlertManager and it launches in onPause() and releases in onResume() methods. Too many switches between onPause/onResume causing inaccuracies in restore time. Target SDK is 15, minimal - 8. I've tested on HTC One V with 4.03

Comment: What I do is, I have a boolean (isInactive) that I set to true in onPause method triggering that the app is going into the background. In onResume, I set it back to false. This works for me. If you have many activities, you may want to do it on all.

Comment: I'll think about this approach. Thanks for your efforts!